# Create multiple username and UID in Linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, useradd

In my environment I constantly have to attach an NFS server running on Linux. The Linux client system has user names created in it and they are in a sequential order. But in order to set the sharing permission for each user individually, I have to create them using `useradd -u 2001 -g 1000 -d /home/app/mnt/1 user1` in my NFS server. If my client system has 1000 users I have to individually crate them on my NFS server too.

I want to create multiple user names and assign an UID (not random) using shell script in my Linux NFS server. I also want to assign them a home directory automatically. For example I want to create users like

```
| Username| UID |Home Directory|
|  user1  |20001|/home/users/1 |
|  user2  |20002|/home/users/2 |
|  user3  |20003|/home/users/3 |
|    .    |  .  |       .      |
|    .    |  .  |       .      |
|    .    |  .  |       .      |
|  userX  |2000X|/home/users/X |
```

User name always starts with "user", it remains the same. **X** could be 100 to 1000.

These users are necessary but short lived hence I don't want to go for a central user management platform. Is it possible that a shell script can create users in bulk?

I went through this [article](http://www.linuxnix.com/create-multiple-users-linux/). This starts with exactly what I want, but later goes into things which makes no sense to me.

Comment: "necessary but short lived" To me, that sounds like an excellent reason to use a user database other than files—a lot of them are far easier to interact with programmatically (e.g., your favorite programming/scripting language has LDAP and SQL interfaces), and you don't have to worry about syncing between systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, this is fairly easy to accomplish. On the terminal you could use a for loop like this:

```
for i in {20001..20100}; do useradd -u $i -g 1000 -d /home/app/mnt/$i "user${i}"; done
```

The loop is incremented up to `20100` and then it quits.